# Word to describe a company's brand, products and services

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a word or phrase that sums up a company's brand, products and services. I'm thinking something along the lines of "company initiatives," but that doesn't seem to sum up the three.

Comment: Maybe *portfolio*

Comment: Or maybe *corporate image* or *corporate identity*

Comment: Maybe _offerings_

Comment: public face[[[[

Answer (score 2):

A number of options:

- Culture
- Portfolio
- Service
- Group of Services
- Presence
- Appearance
- System
- Assets

None of them really match perfectly, but they might get the point across.